# IC Enable Pin not working as expected

Tags: digital-logic, pic, k-bus

I'm working with a [TH3122](https://www.semiee.com/file/EOL/Melexis-TH3122.pdf) I/K-Bus transceiver with a built in 5v/100mA regulator. I'm trying to use my [PIC24FJ1024GA606](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30010074e.pdf) to pull the EN pin of the TH3122 up/down in order to enable and disable the regulator.

Per the TH3122 datasheet, the regulator works this way:

> The regulator is active and can only switched off with a
>   falling edge on EN. The regulator remain with EN=high in
>   active mode and therefore also the VCC voltage is active.
>   The input EN has an internal pull down resistor. If
>   EN=high, the internal pull down current is switched off to
>   minimize the quiescent current.

I have the EN pin pulled up to 5v through a 10k resistor and the regulator turns on as expected. **However**, when I pull the EN pin down (via the PIC's LATCH for the pin), the regulator drops to 2.75v. I have verified that there are only a couple mV on the EN pin when it's pulled down.

What am I missing? For what it's worth, if I wire EN directly to 5v, the regulator drops to zero voltage as soon as it starts floating (5v removed).

Here are the electrical characteristics for the EN pin (min/typical/max/unit for the last four columns):
[image]

P.S. I'm not an EE, so I apologize if I have missed any details.

P.P.S Here's the schematic around the part (GND4 floating isn't an issue anymore as I solder bridged it to another ground):

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other connections such as data lines going to what the regulator powers? Those will need to be taken low, too, as you generally can't have I/Os outside a part's supply voltage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - The regulator isn't power anything right now. It has a cap and that's it. The end goal is to hook the 12v to 5v switching regulator's EN pin to this 5V rail, that way I can shut the entire unit off until the TH3122 gets a data packet.

Comment: Try adding a resistor to drain the cap.

Comment: Just a resistor to ground? My DMM shows a consistent voltage on the output (2.2uF) cap.

Comment: @t3ddftw - Hi, (a) "*I have verified that there are only a couple mV on the EN pin when it's pulled down*" How did you verify that? DMM or scope? If you have a scope, please confirm that the `EN` signal really is a solid low when it should be. (b) When VCC = 2.75V, what does that look like on a scope? (c) "*the regulator drops to zero voltage as soon as it starts floating (5v removed)*" That test suggests that `EN` floating = regulator "off" (as expected). Have you tried changing the code on your PIC24 to set that output to a "Hi-Z" state, instead of driving it low, and then see what happens?

Comment: @SamGibson - Thanks! I don't have access to a scope, unfortunately. The DMM is what is showing a few mV on the `EN` pin. I have not tried setting the pin to hi-z -- I'll give that a shot!

Comment: @t3ddftw - Thanks for the reply. (d) "*The DMM is what is showing a few mV on the EN pin.*" I understand. However the problem is a DMM won't show rapid changes. It is easy to be misled by a DMM reading and expect that things are in a steady state, when in fact something more complicated is happening. (e) "*I don't have access to a scope, unfortunately.*" That may affect the ability to troubleshoot this efficiently :-( If budget allows, you may want to consider buying one (you can buy a cheap one for the same cost as renting for relatively few weeks, these days). (f) Can you add a schematic?

Comment: @SamGibson - Ah, thanks for clarification! Yeah, I've been looking on eBay for a good deal on a digital scope, because you're right, I need one. Schematic has been added to the OP. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you have **nothing** connected as a load, what discharges the output capacitor.  Add a resistor to output as a dummy load.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the DMM begin discharging the output cap? The voltage stays pretty steady. I'll try adding a resistor for testing :)

Comment: I tried setting the pin to hi-z without any success. I also enabled open-drain on the pin, tied a 75k ohm resistor from the output cap to ground and tried another pin. Nothing was successful, so I guess I'll have to fiddle with it using a scope.

Comment: @t3ddftw - Agreed, looking for anomalies using a scope seems sensible. Re-reading your question, I realise that some tests are not *completely* clear to me e.g. you reported a test where the EN pin is *floating* (and VCC is then low, as expected after a high -> low EN transition, due to internal pull-down) - but schematic shows a 10k pull-up, so unless you also disconnect that resistor (which you don't mention doing), EN isn't floating at that point. Summary: There seems to be difference(s) (as yet unknown) between the tests done with PIC24 signal attached, and that signal detached. Good luck!

Comment: @SamGibson - My apologies about the discrepancies in the OP. I tried it _both_ ways (with and without a 10k pull-up) both with the PIC24 and with directly connecting the signal to 5v. As expected, VCC did not go low with the 5v pull-up under any circumstances. Thanks again for your help :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by breaking it out onto a breadboard. Essentially, the PIC24's UART module is keeping the TX pin pulled high, which for some reason is impacting the `EN` pin on the TH3122 and keeping the voltage at 2.7v. The fix here is to disable the UART module before pulling `EN` low, then the TH3122's vreg shuts down as expected.